# Paging in a Gridview. Getting error if the user changes search criteria before clicking on a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a page where the user is able to specify a few different search criterion and click a search button. This populate a gridview based on the results and the user is able to perform various actions on the records. The gridview supports paging

It works well unless the user changes any of the search fields without actually clicking the search button, and then clicking to a new page.

This is occuring because I am handling my paging kind of like this

```
protected void gridview1t_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
{
    gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridview1.DataSource = GetMyData();
    gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

GetMyData() take values that the user entered and passes them to a stored procedure which returns a recordset. So if the search parameters are not the same when a new page is selected, the procedure will return a different set of records than was originally returned. This looks odd from the end user point of view.

I could store my datatable in the session but that doesn't seem like the best solution. Likewise I could stored the parameters from my initial search but that also seems like it might get sloppy. Is there a nice clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Some kind of hint as to what the problem is would probably help us provide a solution e.g. what is the error what is the code of `GetMyData()` do you have any idea of what is causing the probelm etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may save new search criteria in Session or ViewState on Search button click and use that saved criteria in the `GetMyData` method.

Comment: If GetMyData() simply reads the values from a bunch of controls it should not matter whether the user clicks a search button or pages the grid a postback is a postback

Answer (score 0):

I would have the control that is used for search criteria do a postback when changed, then on postbacks redo your databinding so that there is never a difference between the search criteria and the data in the grid.

Comment: I don't think I can do this as one of the controls is a textbox

Comment: To resolve that I personally would use jquery to fire an event which would trigger a postback on the .blur of your textbox. Then it would rebind your grid for text as well.

Comment: actually... a better question is... do you NEED to be doing the databind() within your paging index change? The data should already be bound and you should just be paging through it, not rebinding no?

Answer (score 0):

For my own curiosity, can you just take out the call to getmydata(), just set your page index, and rebind your gridview. I beleive this would resolve the issue of having new search data.

```
protected void gridview1t_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
{
    gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This approach works only with binding using datasource controls like SqlDataSource placed on a page.

Comment: ahhh ok, that's actually what I'm most used to so that makes sense.

Comment: well... also i think that using the SQLDataSource would then be a proposal for him, he could use his GetMyData as the SelectCommand.